# High CPU usage & "Very High" Power usage with PowerShell Start-Sleep

Tags: powershell, cpu-usage

I created a PowerShell script in Windows 10 to display an icon in the system tray and change the icon depending on whether or not Caps Lock is on. (I have a keyboard that has no indicator for Caps Lock).
The script is quite simple (like me) but involves an infinite loop so it will continuously check.

When I use the following line to determine the loop interval the PowerShell instance uses 16% CPU and "Very High" Power usage according to Task Manager:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.5
```

However when I use the following line to determine the loop interval the PowerShell instance uses ~0% CPU and "Very Low" Power usage according to Task Manager:

```
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
```

This, in spite of the fact that the time intervals are the same. Needless to say, I am going with the second option (I even reduced it to 200ms, better response and still no issues).

I was wondering, does anyone know why using fractions of "Seconds" causes such a radical increase in CPU usage?
(I am guessing that the relatively high CPU usage is where the "Very High" power using is coming from).

I thought maybe it is because the CPU is converting data types, although it still seems a little extreme to me, so I tried:

```
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1.5
```

This resulted in ~0% CPU and "Very Low" Power usage according to Task Manager....

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface:

- The answer below assumes that you're using [*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md), because the legacy PowerShell edition, ***Windows PowerShell***, **doesn't support *fractional* seconds** with [`Start-Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/start-sleep)'s **`-Seconds` parameter** (it **quietly converts to `[int]`**, which, in the case of **`0.5`**, **means** that **`0`** is effectively used, and, in the case of `1.5`, due to implicit *half-to-even* rounding, it is `2`); it does, however, support the `-Milliseconds` parameter.
- In other words:

  - **In *Windows PowerShell*, if you want *sub-second granularity*, you *must* use `-Milliseconds`, not `-Seconds`**, e.g. `-Milliseconds 500` rather than `-Seconds 0.5`

    - As noted, in Windows PowerShell **`Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.5`** is the **same as `Start-Sleep -Seconds 0`**, which means that ***you're not sleeping at all*, and creating *only unnecessary overhead*** - this would explain your high CPU utilization.
  - In ***PowerShell (Core) v7+***, you're **free to use *either* parameter**, because the **`-Seconds`** parameter is **now `[double]`-typed and therefore accepts fractional values** (see below).

---

If you're observing an unusual CPU spike in *PowerShell (Core) 7+*, you're most likely seeing a *momentary measuring artifact*: there should be no  *appreciable* difference in performance between `-Seconds 0.5` and `-Milliseconds 0.5`:

As [the source code](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/109c2425aced495d3ce31fb75242c3a19fb3f748/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility/commands/utility/StartSleepCommand.cs#L106-L112) shows, the *only* extra work that use of `-Seconds` incurs (vs. `-Milliseconds`) is the following single statement:

```
(int)(Seconds * 1000);
```

That is, the `-Seconds` value, which is of type `[double]`, is converted to *milliseconds* (as an `[int]` value), and it is that millisecond value that is ultimately passed to the underlying .NET API, the [`System.Threading.Thread.Sleep`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Threading.Thread.Sleep) method.

Note that PowerShell, especially shortly after startup, may be performing *background* operations that impact its overall CPU utilization.

Comment: It seems you are right. I tried again just now and the response with "-Seconds 0.5" seems instantaneous (much faster than 0.5s) which is awesome, but I am not willing to fry my CPU so I will stick with the -Milliseconds 200 which is responsive enough for my purposes.

Comment: @OllyJ0909, I realized that you may be using _Windows PowerShell_ after all, right? In that case, `Start-Sleep -Seconds 0.5` is the same as `Start-Sleep 0`, meaning: _you're not sleeping at all_, and creating _only overhead_. Indeed, in Windows PowerShell you must use `-Milliseconds` for sub-second precision.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I am using Windows PowerShell ISE. Sorry for the lack of clarity. Thanks for your help in understanding this issue.

Comment: As an aside: The PowerShell ISE is [no longer actively developed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/introducing-the-windows-powershell-ise#support) and [there are reasons not to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57134096/45375) (bottom section), notably not being able to run PowerShell (Core) 7+. The actively developed, cross-platform editor that offers the best PowerShell development experience is [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell).

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Silly me, I thought Microsoft would continue developing PowerShell ISE seeing as they shipped it with Windows and seems to be created for utilizing native windows OS features., commands etc...anyway, VS Code it shall be...(for now?)

Answer (score 2):

If I did `while (1) { start-sleep -seconds 0 }`, I would use close to 100% of one of my cores too.  (-seconds is an int32 parameter in powershell 5.1, and `[int32]0.5 -eq 0`) (sysinternals process explorer)

[image]